# Image imported as plane, worked as mesh, but does not rotate around origin

Tags: objects

I imported an image as plane, then I worked on it as if it was any mesh, but now I see it doesn't rotate around its origin, but around the world origin.
How do I fix this?

I tried to unparent, but it didn't work.

Now, I again have some sort of origin, for some reason, but luckily the rotation happens locally.

[image]

Maybe some colliding shortcut? I am trying to narrow down the problem, it seems only to arise when I enter isolation mode.

Comment: make sure that your Transform Pivot Point is set to Median Point for example

Comment: screenhot? (Win Shft S on windows)

Comment: I solved by duplicating the object and deleting the original.

Comment: I don't know what screenshot I could post... it simply showed the original with its good old origin point at the center of the plane (now a framed painting) but it kept rotating based on world origin. I didn't change anything, I duplicated the object and it just works. Probably the original "image to plane" objects are bound to world origin for rotation, I don't know.